# Defining a psql C function gives a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Tags: postgresql, table-functions

I am trying to write a function for Postgres 9.6 that access some code written in C.

My function is defined as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION graph_cluster_graph (sql text, has_rcost boolean)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
    '$libdir/libpgrouting-2.4', 'dir_graph_cluster_desc'
    LANGUAGE c STABLE STRICT;
```

---

When trying to invoke it with:

```sql
select * from   graph_cluster_graph('select * from case3_cab_dist_table',true);
```

I get the error

> definition list is required for functions returning "`record`"

---

It works if I write

```sql
select graph_cluster_graph('select * from case3_cab_dist_table',true);
```

In this case, it invokes the requested C function and then bails out when it returns.

I did change the name of the C function just to find out what would happen (you can an error about being unable to find the function).  So I know it can find my C routine.  Again using the 2nd form of the `select` statement and get a response means that the C function has been correctly invoked.

Has anybody any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: This is not related to that your function is written in `C`. It happens with all functions, which has a return type of `record`. And it happens because the query parser cannot resolve `select *` in that case, unless you explicitly use aliases for every column it returns (within that call).

Comment: Does it work with `RETURNS TABLE (...)` (with ... being the correct names and types as you would specify it in `CREATE TABLE`)?

Comment: See f.ex. [`crosstab()` examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a function that `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` the query parser does not know which columns the result rows will have, and you will have to supply that information in the query.

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) says,

> In some cases it is useful to define table functions that can return
>   different column sets depending on how they are invoked. To support this,
>   the table function can be declared as returning the pseudotype record.
>   When such a function is used in a query, the expected row structure must
>   be specified in the query itself, so that the system can know how to parse
>   and plan the query. This syntax looks like:
>
> `function_call [AS] alias (column_definition [, ... ])
>   function_call AS [alias] (column_definition [, ... ])
>   ROWS FROM( ... function_call AS (column_definition [, ... ]) [, ... ] )`

If you know in advance what columns the record will have, it is better to defined the function as

`RETURNS SETOF datatype`

or

`RETURNS TABLE ( column_name column_type [, ...] )`

The latter is a shorthand for the older syntax:

`funcname(..., OUT column_name column_type, ...) RETURNS SETOF record`

Comment: Thanks,  now I understand the context of the error message
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  graph_cluster_graph (edges_sql text, has_rcost boolean,OUT seq integer, OUT id integer, OUT cluster_group integer)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
Does the trick

Comment: Right, that's another option. the `TABLE (...)` syntax I suggested is a shorthand for what you ended up using. I'll include this (older) variant for completeness' sake.